# Getting 500 - Internal Server Error with Ajax Jquery Method for an Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, sql, entity-framework

I did [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692793/Introduction-to-Knockout-js-and-CRUD-Operations-in) to get warm with SQL-Databases and the Entity-Frameworks and Knockout.js.

I thought I could arrange the code to get connected to my own database.

In order to develop a MVVM based webapplication this is the ViewModel:
[ViewModel with observation calls in Javascript by Knockout.js]

```js
    function Device(data) {
        this.Date = ko.observable(data.Date);
        this.Value = ko.observable(data.Value);
        this.ObjectID = ko.observable(data.ObjectID);
        this.TypeID = ko.observable(data.TypeID);
    }


    function DeviceViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.Devices = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.Date = ko.observable();
        self.Value = ko.observable();
        self.ObjectID = ko.observable();
        self.TypeID = ko.observable();

       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'LearnKO.aspx/FetchDevices',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (results) {
                var devices = $.map(results.d, function (item) {
                    return new Device(item)

                });
                self.Devices(devices);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        })
    }
$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new StudentViewModel());
});
```

The ajax method should call a webMethod in an .aspx.cs data:

```
[WebMethod]

public static DEVICE_VALUES[] FetchDevices()
{   
    DiagmaResultsEntities dbEntitiesDiagma = new 
        DiagmaResultsEntities();
    var dataDiagma = (from item in dbEntitiesDiagma.DEVICE_VALUES
                      orderby item.Value
                      select item).Take(12);
    return dataDiagma.ToArray();
}
```

And this is my SQL-Database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNLc4.png)

I want to get "date","value","ObjectID", and "typeID" out of that EF. But im getting this error and can't find myself a possible solution with google.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: jquery throws an exception and the messagebox pops up: "500 - Internal Server Error"

Comment: Well, ASP.NET typically gives a response body that gives information about the error, or how to turn on the display of error information. Read the response.

Comment: after i rebuild the solution there is no more exception just the 500 - internal server Error

Comment: this error is thrown by the ajax call itself. so something must be wrong with this method.

Comment: Dude. The response code comes from the server. You may well be sending bad data to the server, causing the 500 error (an exception). But the response will tell you what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by giving out the response body like i got told:

```js
$.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: 'LearnKO.aspx/FetchDevices',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            var devices = $.map(results.d, function (item) {
                return new Device(item)

            });
            self.Devices(devices);
        },

        error: function (err) {
            //alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            console.log(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            console.log(err.responseText);

        }
    });
```

I got the following errorcode:
[errorcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaHuf.png)

The json serializer seems to have problems with " circular references".

Ended up by adding only one Table from those database and was able to show my data.

Thanks for help.